# AWS Rails Capistrano PG Error on Deployment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, capistrano

I've been struggling for a while to deploy a rails postgres app onto EC2. Right now, I'm getting this error:

bundle stdout: An error occurred while installing pg (0.18.3), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install pg -v '0.18.3'` succeeds before bundling.

The EC2 instance is on ubuntu 14 and I have followed this guide exactly:

http://www.sitepoint.com/deploy-your-rails-app-to-aws/

Any help would be awesome, pg is installed with both:
sudo apt-get install libpq-dev
 and gem install pg.

Answer (score 0):

Install the following lib in your server (set the version that you need)

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql-server-dev-9.3
```

and then

```
gem install pg
```